# Error response mapping angular2

Tags: angular

i have angular2 code for service get

```
getkokabname(id){
  let url = "http://localhost:8080/regencies/name/"+id;
  let header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'});
  return this.http.get(url, {headers: header})
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res:Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || [];
}

private handleError(error:any) {
      // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
      // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
      let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
          error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
      console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
      return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

if i access the url using postman. it return text like this KABUPATEN SUMENEP. but at my code it return Unexpected token K in JSON at position 0. How to resolve that?

here it is my code for access the value

```
kokabname(){
    this.service.getkokabname(this.gov).subscribe(
      data=> this.governmentname = data,
      err => err
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> your service should be like

```
 getkokabname(id){
      let url = "http://localhost:8080/regencies/name/"+id;
      let header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'});
      return this.http.get(url, {headers: header})
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(
                (error: Response) => {
                    return Observable.throw(error.json());
                });
    }
```